# How can I get values of a child whose key is known to me?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got the key of specific child using `snapshot.getkey();` and stored it in a string and now I want to access that child's values at other location.

Comment: Have you already taken a tour through stackoverflow? There are some points to help you getting satisfied answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether this may be useful.
You can get the collection object from firebase with the specific child key which you have stored in a string.
The following function will fetch the child object based on the key.You can implement this in javascript function at any point so that you can retrieve the data.

```
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('CollectionName/' + key );
  starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var collectionObj = snapshot.val();

  })
```

Comment: Can you give the code in java ,for android ,it would be very helpful